# phpize Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php

Tags: php, centos, pecl

stack: PHP 5.4.23, php-fpm, nginx 1.4.x, centos 6.5

I was trying to install xdebug, had to run phpize command.

I have php5-devl already installed and pecl command works

When I ran the command, it gave me the following error output:

```
# phpize
Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Are PHP headers at `/usr/include/php`?

Answer (score 20):

I think you have not installed `php-pear` . I am not seeing it in that link.

You can do it by `yum install php-pear`

**Info**

You can install xdebug also using these steps

1) Install PHP’s devel package for PHP commands execution

```
yum install php-devel
```

Make sure you also have php-pear package installed

```
yum install php-pear
```

2) Install GCC and GCC C++ compilers to compile Xdebug extension yourself.

`yum install gcc gcc-c++ autoconf automake`

3) Compile Xdebug

`pecl install Xdebug`

4) Find the php.ini file using

```
`locate php.ini`
```

And add the following line

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/usr/lib64/php/modules/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
```

5) Restart Apache
`service httpd restart`

6) Test if it works – create test.php with the following code

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Answer (score 9):

The problem got solved by the PHP version that is used in the system.

My PHP Version was 5.6

So by running the following command I solved the problem

```
yum install php56-devel
```

Where "56" is your version of PHP.

Comment: getting failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yum install php56-devel]: exit code: 1

Answer (score 1):

If you're on PHP 7 such as in my case just installing `php-devel` won't solve your problems, but you'll need to install some additional packages:

`yum install php-devel pcre-devel gcc make`

And then you'll be able to follow Harikrishnan steps to get xdebug working (if not yet configured).

Comment: Error: php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-45.el7.x86_64

Comment: In fact if you read my answer starts with *if you're on PHP7*

Comment: @Eddie This link solves the php70w-common conflict with php-common-5.4.16.el7.x86_64 https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-or-upgrade-to-php-7-on-centos-linux-server . Basically, install php7 in your centOS system enabling Remi and EPEL repos.

Answer (score 0):

My problem hasn't been solved using

```
yum install php-devel
```

But this helped me to solve the problem:

```
yum --enablerepo=remi,remi-php55 install php55-php-devel
```

Comment: If you use "remi" repository, you probably don't need to build any pecl extension, most are available in the repository ;) See the list on http://blog.remirepo.net/pages/PECL-extensions-RPM-status